# Run a code in python 2 in jupyter notebook in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

My jupyter notebook is runing python 3 and need to run a code writen in python 2. I remember that is possible in python 2 to make a call from the future and run a codenin python 3. Is it possible to do the reverse?

Comment: "I remember that is possible in python 2 to make a call from the future and run a codenin python 3." That's not really how `__future__` works. Can you update the Python 2 code?

Comment: Why don't you just install Python 2 on jupyter as well? You can follow this: https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/issues/71#issuecomment-159927298

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna try that. Thanks!